# Non trivial Open-Closed sets

Tags: general-topology

in topology is possible to have subsets of a topological space that are both open and closed. 
I know some trivial examples (the whole set and connected components of non connected sets). My question is the following:

What are interesting, trivial and complicated examples of open-closed sets?

With complicated I mean anything that is not obvious and requires even a very small proof

Thank you

Comment: Literally anything, given the right topology.

Comment: It depends on your topology. For example in the discrete topology any set is both open and closed.

Comment: Think about the Cantor set for more interesting examples.

Comment: In the usual topology, the Cantor set is closed, but it isn't open, is it, @Moishe ?

Comment: For spaces with finitely many connected components, clopen sets correspond to unions of connected components. For spaces with infinitely many connected components, all clopen sets are still unions of connected components, but the converse may not be true.

Comment: I think it's hard to answer this question unless you specify in what way you want them to be interesting or non-trivial. For example, you list "connected componeents of non-connected sets" as examples, but any clopen set of a topological space must be the (possibly infinite) union of connected components of that space.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Cantor set as a topological space has many interesting clopen subsets.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers you're received, Alfred?

Comment: Earth to Alfred – come in, please.

Answer (score 2):

There's a topology on the integers generated by the (two-sided infinite) arithmetic progressions. Since the complement of an arithmetic progression is a union of arithmetic progressions, each arithmetic progression is both open and closed in this topology.

It's not just a curiosity – this topology has been used to prove the existence of infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 2):

The Stone space of a Boolean algebra is quite a natural place where clopen sets occur (many special examples in general topology are zero-dimensional, i.e. have a base of open-and-closed (clopen) sets): if $(A, \land, \lor, \lnot,0,1)$ is a Boolean algebra, on the set of filters of $A$ (special collections of subsets of $A$) we can put a topology such that the resulting $\textrm{Stone}(X)$ Strone space of $X$ is compact Hausdorff and such that it has a base of clopen subsets such that those clopen subsets (which in a fixed space $S$ always form a Boolean algebra under $\cap$, $\cup$ and complementation, and $\emptyset$, $S$ as minimum and maximum) are an isomorphic algebra to $A$. So essentially, all Boolean algebras can be seen as the set of clopen subsets of a compact Hausdorff space, which allows for many nice connections between Boolean algebra theory and general topology. Look for "Stone duality" online for more info.